# How can I find the dictionary with the most keys on my list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

I have a list containing dictionaries, and I want to get the dictionary containing the highest number of keys.

How can I do that, and what is the most efficient way?

For the list:

```py
myList = [
    {
        'foo':12,
        'bar':14,
        'ali':34,
        'met':45
    },
    {
        'moo':52
    },
    {
        'doo':6,
        'tar':84,
        'moo':52
    }
]
```

I would like to get `result = {'foo':12, 'bar':14, 'ali':34, 'met':45}`

Comment: "Most" in what terms? By the sum of values or the highest value?

Comment: What do you mean by largest number of keys, which value appears for different keys, so the same keys also count? What do you mean by best? What is your concrete problem with doing this? Have you googles dictionary to find out what you can do with it?

Comment: has the largest number of keys, so key count

Comment: Do you have a concrete question or do you just need someone to write this for you?

Comment: "dictionary with most keys" Do you mean number of elements in the dictionary?

Comment: Yuri Ginsburg, yeah ı do mean it

Comment: `max(myList, key=len)`

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so the shortest way to return the dictionary with a maximum number of keys is:

```py
result = max(myList, key=len)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the best way to do that is by using the `max` function with the `key` argument that you set yourself. The `key` argument is the function that will be used to compare elements.
Here if you want to compare the size of the dictionaries, your function would be something like

```
def comp_func(dic) :
    return len(dic)
```

and then you can use the max function like this

```
max_dict = max(myList, key=comp_func)
```

you could also use a lambda function (which I think is the best solution)

```
max_dict = max(myList, key=lambda dic: len(dic))
```

EDIT

Actually, like another answer said, you don't have to recreate a function just to use `len`, so the best would be

```
max_dict = max(myList, key=len)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another more long-winded (but perhaps more intuitive) way of doing it:

```
myList = [
    {
        'foo': 12,
        'bar': 14,
        'ali': 34,
        'met': 45
    },
    {
        'moo': 52
    },
    {
        'doo': 6,
        'tar': 84,
        'moo': 52

    }
]

lengths = []

for i, d in enumerate(myList):
    lengths.append(len(d.keys()))

index = lengths.index(max(lengths))

print(myList[index])
```

Comment: More intuitive? I would probably never think of adding extra space complexity for such a simple task.

Comment: @VisioN I think you're answer is the better one. Relax.

Comment: I wouldn't argue on that `:)` but more intuitive would probably be having a reference to the largest dict before the loop, which you compare with `len(d)` in the loop, rather than having a list of lengths, i.e. `res = {}; for d in myList: if len(res) < len(d): res = d;`